# Error trying to send image in wordpress api

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm trying to use wordpress API to send an image to wordpress (I aim to then use it in a post, also created with the API). This is my code:

```
data = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "test.png"), "rb").read()
    filename="test"
    extension = "png"
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename,
        'content-type': 'image/%s' % extension
    }
    r = requests.post(url + '/media', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I get the following error in response :

```
{"code":"rest_upload_sideload_error","message":"D\u00e9sol\u00e9, ce type de fichier n\u2019est pas autoris\u00e9 pour des raisons de s\u00e9curit\u00e9.","data":{"status":500}}
```

For those who don't understand french at all, it says that for security reasons, this type of files is not allowed.I don't understand why, png is not a very special format, and my image is a random simple image taken on internet for my tests. I also tried an ico file, same result.
I know that the credential part is working since I used it to test the API for posting a post, which worked.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Makes me wonder if your filename in the content-disposition shouldn't also contain the extension.   filename.png rather then 'filename'

Comment: I gave it a try, same result...

Comment: Does your api work on a simpler endpoint?  For example listing blogposts?

Comment: Like I said in my post, it works fine for posting a post on my blog. So the authentification should work since I use the same and likewise for the url.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out!

I had two things to change in my initial code posted above.
First, as S.D suggested, I had to include the extension in my filenam and second, send the file in the data, not in files.
Corrected working code:

```
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.png',
        'Content-type': 'image/png'
    }
    data = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "test.png"), "rb").read();
    r = requests.post(url + '/media', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Hope this may help others, I really struggled finding the last part of the problem.